# Magento 2: how to use the collection walk iterator?

Tags: magento2, collection, performance, best-practice

Back in Magento 1, it was possible to use the collection iterator to walk through the results and avoid looping through them.

It was a huge improvement in terms of performance when dealing with massive collections.

Here is some sample code of what could be done.

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('firstname'), 'inner');
// call iterator walk method with collection query string and callback method as parameters
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($customers->getSelect(), array(array($this, 'customerCallback')));
```

Then you could define a callback function `customerCallback` to process the results one by one.

Is that still possible in Magento 2? If so how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it still seems to be there: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/ResourceModel/Iterator.php

Usage should be the same as in M1

Comment: is it possible to add for example $resultArray[] = $orderId in the run function and then access $resultArray variable outside the 'run' callback after the $iterator->walk routine ends?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible! It's very similar to Magento 1, by the way.

`\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator` has the `walk` function which will call your callback function for every single item, rather than the entire collection at once.

```
public function iterator()
{
    // you can filter by attribute
    // $this
    //    ->collection // \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
    //    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['like' => '%samsung%']);

    $this
        ->iterator // \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator
        ->walk(
            $this->collection->getSelect(),
            [[$this, 'callback']]
        );
}

public function callback($args)
{
    // load of the product
    $product = $this
        ->productRepository // \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
        ->getById($args['row']['entity_id']);

    // do whatever you want to with the $product
    print_r($product->debug());
}
```

I also have written a [blog post about working with large collections in Magento 2](http://www.matheusgontijo.com/2018/02/10/magento-2-working-with-large-collections-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-xxxx-bytes-exhausted/). And [here are an example project](https://github.com/matheusgontijo/blog-examples/tree/master/2018-02-10-magento-2-working-with-large-collections-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-xxxx-bytes-exhausted/MatheusGontijo/Iterator).

Comment: How can i implement these

Comment: @Matheus is it possible to add for example $resultArray[] = $orderId in the run function and then access $resultArray variable outside the 'run' callback after the $iterator->walk routine ends?

Comment: @Radu I'm not quite sure if I understood what you mean, but if I'm correct, yes you can. You could save the order ids on the object property itself. For example: $this->resultArray[] = ...    Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\IteratorFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactoryInterface;
use Zend_Db_Select;

class RunSomeLongTask
{
    public const ORDER_STATE_VALUE = 'example';

    /** @var CollectionFactoryInterface  */
    private $orderCollectionFactory;

    /** @var IteratorFactory */
    private $iteratorFactory;

    /** @var SomeTask */
    private $someTask;

    /**
     * constructor.
     * @param CollectionFactoryInterface $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param IteratorFactory $iteratorFactory
     * @param SomeTask $someTask
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactoryInterface $orderCollectionFactory,
        IteratorFactory $iteratorFactory,
        SomeTask $someTask
    ) {
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->iteratorFactory = $iteratorFactory;
        $this->someTask = $someTask; // "important: remember create this class"
    }

    public function process(): void
    {
        $orderCollection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();

        $orderCollection
            ->getSelect()
            ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns(['entity_id', 'state', 'status'])
            ->where('state=?', self::ORDER_STATE_VALUE);

        /** @var Iterator $iterator */
        $iterator = $this->iteratorFactory->create();

        $iterator->walk($orderCollection->getSelect(), [[
            $this->someTask, // instance of class SomeTask
            'run' // the function in your class "SomeTask"
        ]]);
    }
}

class SomeTask
{
    public function run(array $args): void
    {
        // you will receive the row data here
        
        $orderId = $args['row']['entity_id'];

        // do your task here on individual row
    }
}
```

Explained well on
http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/collection-walk-iterator.php

Comment: is it possible to add for example $resultArray[] = $orderId in the run function and then access $resultArray variable outside the 'run' callback after the $iterator->walk routine ends?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with `Iterator`!
According to my benchmarks it seems Iterator loads **all data** at same time! It loads in a flat array, not objects - so it takes less memory.

I prefer old-fashion way to loop the collection - page by page:

```
    $collection->setPageSize(50);
    $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
    for ($pageNum = 1; $pageNum<=$pages; $pageNum++) {
        $collection->setCurPage($pageNum);
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            //Do something.
        }
        $collection->clear();
    }
```

Full example is here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/273437/48222

#### Iterator.Benchmark:

###### Code

```
        print_mem();

        $iterator = $this->iteratorFactory->create();
        $iterator->walk($collection->getSelect(), [
            function ($batch) {
                print_mem();
                $this->batchProcessor->executeRow($batch);
            }
        ]);
```

###### Output

```
//Before `Iterator::walk`
^ "The script is now using: 87 403 KB of memory."
^ "Peak usage: 87 943KB of memory."

//Inside `Iterator::walk`
^ "The script is now using: 1 315 666 KB of memory."
^ "Peak usage: 1 315 666 KB of memory."
```

#### Collection page-by-page.Benchmark:

###### Code

```
        print_mem();

        $collection->setPageSize(10);

        $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
        for ($pageNum = 1; $pageNum<=$pages; $pageNum++) {
            $collection->setCurPage($pageNum);
            foreach ($collection as $batch) {
                print_mem();
                $this->batchProcessor->execute($batch);
            }
            $collection->clear();
        }
```

###### Output

```
//Before
^ "The script is now using: 87 403 KB of memory."
^ "Peak usage: 87 943 KB of memory."

//Inside `foreach(collection)`
^ "The script is now using: 97 013 KB of memory."
^ "Peak usage: 106 350 KB of memory." //an order of magnitude less
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this solution could be usefull in some cases for Magento 2

```
use Magento\Framework\DB\Query\Generator;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Query\BatchIteratorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

//class SomeClass ...

private ResourceConnection $resourceConnection;
private Generator $queryGenerator;
private LoggerInterface $logger;
public int $affectedRows = 0;

public function __construct(
    ResourceConnection $connection,
    Generator $queryGenerator,
    LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->resourceConnection = $connection;
    $this->queryGenerator = $queryGenerator;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function getBatches(): \Generator
{
    $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
    $select = $connection->select()
        ->from($this->resourceConnection->getTableName('some_table'), ['entity_id'])
        ->where('field = ?', 'some value')
        ->where('some_field IS NOT NULL')
        ->where('some_another_condition', true);

    $field = 'entity_id'; //or could be non unique field of a table depends on a strategy
    $batchSize = 1000;
    $strategy = BatchIteratorInterface::UNIQUE_FIELD_ITERATOR; // or BatchIteratorInterface::NON_UNIQUE_FIELD_ITERATOR;
    
    $iterator = $this->queryGenerator->generate($field, $select, $batchSize, $strategy);

    foreach ($iterator as $query) {
        yield $connection->fetchCol($query); //could be fetchAll or any other method depends on your needs
    }
}

//Example of using

public function execute(): void
{
    $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();

    try {
        $connection->beginTransaction();
        
        // Here we use our iterator
 
        foreach ($this->getBatches() as $batch) {
  
            //Implementation of logic with our batches
            $this->affectedRows += $connection->update(
                $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('table_name'),
                ['some_column_to_be_clear' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL')],
                ['entity_id IN (?)' => $batch]
            );
        }
        
        $connection->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $connection->rollBack();
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getTrace());
        $this->affectedRows = 0;
        throw $e;
    }
}
```