# How to load product collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-collection, object-manager

How to load product collection in Magento 2 and what is the difference between Magento 1 and Magento 2 load product collection

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35679085/1728526

Comment: You can check this tested version to make sure it work well here https://magento2x.com/how-to-get-product-product-collection-in-magento-2/

Comment: I'm created Magento 2 tutorials channel please Like and Support https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2JghzAPB7wNBDY0u-OtAig/videos

Answer (score 17):

The standard collections are actually very similar. There are other similar structures, but for products you can load them in and load them just like Magento 1. Just like in Magento 1, if you are using the collection via iteration you do not have to load it as it's done implicitly.

As always in Magento 2, you should be injecting classes via dependency injection in your class constructor. Plus, if you are going to create more than one instance you can add "Factory" after any class and you'll get a wrapping class that allows you to generate as many as you want.

Here is the use of both together:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory */
protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function yourMethod()
{
    // Use factory to create a new product collection
    $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    /** Apply filters here */
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    // Don't have to do this
    // $productCollection->load();

    foreach ($productCollection as $product){
         echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
    }  
}
```

With thanks to @megi for the example usage code in their answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
 <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}  
?>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use the objectManager directly, try to use factorys instead as Robert Egginton suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the best way to get product collection in magento

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    )
{
    $this->product = $product;
}

public function getCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->product->create()->getCollection();
    return $collection;
}

public function loadProduct($id)
{
    $product = $this->product->create()->load($id);
    return $product;
}
```

In the magento 1 you can get collection using below code

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

here we call Model **catalog/product** and then getCollection() method to get all product collection

In Magento 2 First we need to call class of product collection **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product**

then we need to call method create();
Magento 2's create method is same as Magento 1's getModel then we call collection.

Comment: Also consider using an Iterator when working with large collections and avoid memory_limit errors. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213059/555

Answer (score 3):

**=> Magento 1 :**

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $prod) {
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());
}
```

**=> Magento 2 :**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: how to get new product collection only?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to load the product collection using repositories in Magento 2 service contracts.

Inject the interface `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` in your constructor as follows

```
protected $productRepo; 

public function __construct(    
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepo
) {
    $this->productRepo = $productRepo;
}

public function getProductById($itemId)
{
    return $this->productRepo->getById($itemId);
}

public function getProductBySku($sku)
{
    return $this->productRepo->get($sku);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Magento 2** getting the product is totally different from Magento 1.
in Magento 1 we use this code to get the collection.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

To get product collection in Magento 2 use following code.

```
 protected $_productCollectionFactory;

 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productFactory;
    }
    public function getProductCollection()
    { 
      return   $this->_productCollectionFactory->create(); 

     }
```

[Reference](http://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento/magento-2-get-product-collection/)

Comment: Hello, Is it possible to apply this new product collection throughout the website ?

Comment: how to filter with most order items, i used below code, its not working, ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');

Comment: @jafarpinjar use order item collections

Comment: @QaisarSatti, i am getting product collection with category filter, how to use with this?

Comment: @jafarpinjar that is not related to this answer. create new question for that

Comment: @QaisarSatti, you can answer here pls, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382355/how-to-get-products-by-category-id-in-magento-2-2-1

Comment: @jafarpinjar this question is not related what you are asking for.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, you can answer now here, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257499/best-seller-items-in-category-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps to load product collection:
**Step 1. Create your own block file**

app/Code/Vendor/ModuleName/Block/ClassName.php

Copy Paste following code into your block file.

    protected $productCollectionFactory;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(5); // Fetch Only 5 Products
    return $collection;
}
```

}

**Step 2: Display product collection in phtml file**

$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());
}

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one it's working for me.**

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()

 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')

 ->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> 1. List item

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can load product collection From Helper also, so that You can use that collection anywhere.like thise...**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
 {
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;

    parent::__construct($context);
}

**/* Get full Products Collection*/**
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(6);
    return $collection;
}
```

}

**Now if you want to call it in any phtml file you can achieve it easily like these.**

```
<?php 
$helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');
$collection = $helper->getProductCollection();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
                 $result = [
                    'id'        => $product->getId(),
                    '_sku'      => $product->getSku(),
                    'product_url' => $product->getProductUrl($product),
                    'title'     => $product->getName(),
                    'raw_price' => $product->getPrice()
                ];
?>
<span class="price">
<?= $result['raw_price'] ?>
</span>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: even if this works, using helpers is not a good practice. Also, putting methods into a helper so you can use them everywhere in templates is even worse.