# Best seller items in category magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, category-products

I have used below code to filter products by category id.

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$catalog_ids = 4;
$productCollection = $_objectManager- >create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()

->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
 ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
 ->load();
```

I am filtering product collection with the category.

Need to filter the collection was most sold items from the category.

How to achieve this. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$catalog_ids = 4;
$productCollection = $_objectManager- >create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()

->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
 ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
 ->load();
```

Logic here

```
$proIds = $collection->getAllIds();

$itemsCollection = $_objectManager- >create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory')->create();
$itemsCollection->addFieldToFilter('product_id', 'in' => $proIds));
$itemCollection ->getSelect()
            ->columns('SUM(qty_ordered) as total_qty')
            ->group('product_id')->setOrder('total_qty');
$bestSeller = $itemsCollection->getColumnValues('product_id');   
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(entity_id,' . implode(',', $bestSeller).')'));
```

Comment: Logic code not working for me

Comment: for this  Logic code purpose Order should have been placed then it load colllections and filter it with products ids

Comment: @HiteshBalpande yes it gets collection from order first.

Comment: Is this working?

Comment: Can you give me an example module link?

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam https://store.qaisarsatti.com/download/magento-2-best-seller-extension/

Comment: It looks fine. But I need to get top 3 most purchased categories? How to implement that? I need the categories list instead of the products list.

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam Now you have the product by sale count get the category by-product it is easy.