# Magento 2.3 - what is the recommended way of looping through a large product collection

Tags: magento2.3, products, data

When working with large product collections (50,000 products +) in Magento 1 I ended up using something similar to the following.

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'visibility'));

    $productsCollection->setPageSize(50);

    $pages = $productsCollection->getLastPageNumber();
    $currentPage = 1;

    do {
        $productsCollection->setCurPage($currentPage);
        $productsCollection->load();

        foreach ($productsCollection as $_product) {

            echo $_product->getId() . "\n";
            echo $_product->getSku() . "\n";
            echo $_product->getName() . "\n";

            /* do stuff */


        }

        $currentPage++;
        //clear collection and free memory
        $productsCollection->clear();
    } while ($currentPage <= $pages);
}
```

Does anyone have experience on working with very large product collections in Magento2? What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone on the magento forum suggested something like this:

```
public function __construct( 

   \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function yourMethod()
{
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(['name','price','visibility']);
    $collection->setPageSize(50);
    $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
    for ($pageNum = 1; $pageNum<=$pages; $pageNum++) {
        $collection->setCurPage($pageNum);
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            //Do something.
        }
        $collection->clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The recent comment reminded me I later came back to this and wrote two versions of an export script borrowing some logic from core for iterator

Uses iterator

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ProductCsvExport/blob/1.0.2/Console/Command/Product.php#L297

Uses collection

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ProductCsvExport/blob/1.0.1/Console/Command/Product.php#L238

Iterator handles memory usage but is much slower approach. If you've got a collections with thousands of products it might be the only suitable approach

Anyway hope helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Also I've come across this:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213059/70343

In theory sound although I've not tested.

Comment: Meh. Loading each product one by one is not a sane option.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this approach could be usefull in your case scenario for Magento 2

```
use Magento\Framework\DB\Query\Generator;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Query\BatchIteratorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

//class SomeClass ...

private ResourceConnection $resourceConnection;
private Generator $queryGenerator;
private LoggerInterface $logger;
public int $affectedRows = 0;

public function __construct(
    ResourceConnection $connection,
    Generator $queryGenerator,
    LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->resourceConnection = $connection;
    $this->queryGenerator = $queryGenerator;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function getBatches(): \Generator
{
    $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();

    $select = $connection->select()
        ->from($this->resourceConnection->getTableName('some_table'), ['entity_id'])
        ->where('field = ?', 'some value')
        ->where('some_field IS NOT NULL')
        ->where('some_another_condition', true);

    // OR $collection->getSelect() could be used instead

    $field = 'entity_id'; //or could be non unique field of a table depends on a strategy
    $batchSize = 1000;
    $strategy = BatchIteratorInterface::UNIQUE_FIELD_ITERATOR; // or BatchIteratorInterface::NON_UNIQUE_FIELD_ITERATOR;

    $iterator = $this->queryGenerator->generate($field, $select, $batchSize, $strategy);

    foreach ($iterator as $query) {
        yield $connection->fetchCol($query); //could be fetchAll or any other method depends on your needs
    }
}

//Example of using

public function execute(): void
{
    $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();

    try {
        $connection->beginTransaction();
    
        // Here we use our iterator

        foreach ($this->getBatches() as $batch) {

            //Example of using our batches
            $this->affectedRows += $connection->update(
                $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('table_name'),
                ['some_column_to_be_clear' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL')],
                ['entity_id IN (?)' => $batch]
            );
        }
    
        $connection->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $connection->rollBack();
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getTrace());
        $this->affectedRows = 0;
        throw $e;
    }
}
```