# How to stop huge memory consumption when iterating over large amount of orders?

Tags: magento2, collection, magento2.4.5, memory

I created a console command to create invoices and shipments for a certain set of orders. The total amount of all affected orders is about 79000. When I execute the command memory consumption is going up linear until out of memory.
At about 14k processed orders it was 7.5G.

```
$ bin/magento order:complete-existing
10183/79288 [===>------------------------]  12%  2 hrs 5.4 GiB
1019414363/79288 [=====>----------------------]  18%  2 hrs 7.5 GiB
```

This is the command I created:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): void
{
    $searchCriteria = $this->getSearchCriteria();
    $orderList = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

    $this->progressBar = new ProgressBar($output, $orderList->getTotalCount());
    $this->progressBar->setFormat("%current%/%max% [%bar%] %percent:3s%% %remaining:6s% %memory:6s%\n");

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $orderList->getLastPageNumber(); $i++) {
        $searchCriteria->setCurrentPage($i);
        $this->invoiceAndShipOrders($this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems());
        $this->progressBar->advance(100);
    }

    $this->progressBar->setFormat(
        "%current%/%max% [%bar%] %percent:3s%% %elapsed:6s%\n"
    );
    $this->progressBar->finish();
}
```

In `invoiceAndShipOrders` I am simply iterating over the orders and create an invoice and shipment:

```
private function invoiceAndShipOrders(array $orders): void
{
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        if (!$order->hasInvoices()) {
            try {
                $this->invoiceOrder->execute(
                    $order->getEntityId(),
                    false,
                    $this->getInvoiceItems($order)
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->error(
                    'Unable to invoice order: ' . $e->getMessage(),
                    ['exception' => $e, 'orderId' => $order->getEntityId()]
                );
            }
        }

        try {
            $this->shipOrder->execute(
                $order->getEntityId(),
                $this->getShipmentItems($order)
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error(
                'Unable to ship order: ' . $e->getMessage(),
                ['exception' => $e, 'orderId' => $order->getEntityId()]
            );
        }

        $this->progressBar->advance();
    }
}
```

Now my question is why is there this huge memory consumption? I am not working with any reference and use a simple 100 items pagination. It seems that every order loaded stays in the memory and is never unset and cleared via garbage collection.

I was wondering if `invoiceAndShipOrders()`  is the issue so I commented the call to it and called just `$this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();` instead. Resulting in the same memory increase:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $orderList->getLastPageNumber(); $i++) {
    $searchCriteria->setCurrentPage($i);
    $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    $this->progressBar->advance(100);
}
```

It seems to me that Magento somehow keeps references to the orders and thus prevents the memory to be cleared. I am wondering where this happens and how I can fix this.

I have also tried using a collection instead of the list but it brings the same result. I did not try an iterator yet as shown in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213059/70510), since it does not seem right to load every order individually. I think there might be a solution with the list/collection.

Comment: MySQL has CONNECT, PROCESS, CLOSE connection structure.  This URL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534568/mysql-connector-python-not-closing-connection-explicitly  - is specific for python but a similar CLOSE is needed to cause resources to be released in a timely manner to avoid OOM in any 'connect'ing environment.

Comment: I have tried to use `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::closeConnection` but that does not seem to help. Watching the process list of the database it seems to be separate queries.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results to justpaste.it a 15 second General Log for analysis?  Remember to SET GLOBAL general_log=OFF; after 15 seconds and FLUSH LOGS; before you save this General Log to your local storage.  Please share the link for analysis.